# Trouble getting information to store in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having issues getting my code to post to my MySQL database, our website doesn't return any errors, just 'Registration Successful' Any help would be appreciated!

If any other details are required, I can post some more code to help. I am very new to Website building and I am legitimately stuck.

Thank you :)

Here is a clip to what happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhU67GD5niI

```html
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['twitch'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $twitch = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'twitch', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }
    
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //
    
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error</p>';
    }
    
    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt, twitch) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $twitch);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../eh/error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
                exit();
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @James Loosely ! Looks like  the driver doesn't catch errors (not very likely) or writes to a database that is not login_secure. Did you check you actually connect to the right database (check your db_connect.php) ? Did you disable autocommit ?

Comment: Thank you! :) It seems everything is alright connection to the database. Here is the code from psl-config.php:

    <?php

HOST", "localhost");    // The host you want to connect to. 
define("USER", "sec_user");    // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "YGBroAqrcLGDzTGd");  // The database password.
define("DATABASE", "secure_login");             // The database name.

define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

define("SECURE", FALSE);    // For development purposes only!!!!
    ?>

Can you clarify what autocommit is?

Comment: and here is the code to db_connect.php:

<?php


include_once 'psl-config.php';   // Needed because functions.php is not included

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    header("Location: ../error.php");
    exit();
}
?>

Comment: Autocommit is a database feature. When the autocommit is not enabled, the INSERT or UPDATE are not actually persisted. When executed by the driver, they look like they were successfully executed (no error is yield) but the content is neither inserted nor updated. If you can, adding logging in your mysql server will help.

Comment: You should NEVER disclose passwords, even if your database is locally hosted.

Comment: Your credentials and database name look correct. Autocommit is generally enabled by default.

Comment: I enabled logging, and found an unexpected character in my psl-config.php file, after ammending it, I still have the same issue and the information still isn't imported into the database.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I will change it now. Thank you for the heads up on the password :)

Comment: Hmm, quite puzzling. When having a look at the mySQL logs, can you spot the SELECT / INSERT queries ? In particular can you spot the INSERT one ?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, there was a configuration issue with my database and after recreating it, I fixed it. Thank you for your help